# Create an array of objects from Firebase of specified keys and values with forEach loop

Tags: arrays, node.js, firebase, foreach, firebase-realtime-database

I need to return a single array of objects from Firebase that I can then manipulate.

The code below logs many arrays of incrementing length. I only need the last array that has the total number of objects with the data available in the child I'm referencing. Once I have this array I need to manipulate it. I'm dealing with court data. `weeklyData` is just the number of people held for x nights before their court appearance.

```js
var weeklyNightsHeld = db.ref(`nightsHeld/weeklyNightsHeld`);
var array = [];

weeklyNightsHeld.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {

  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
    var weeklyData = new Object();
    weeklyData.days = data.key;
    weeklyData.people = data.val();

    array.push(weeklyData)

    console.log(array);
});
  });
```

Here is my Firebase data:

```js
 {
  "nightsHeld" : {
    "weeklyNightsHeld" : {
      "-KgmbMAtaK7AvkaPWv-K" : {
        "1" : 6,
        "5" : 8,
        "6" : 12
      },
      "-Kgmbt-TbnZ8CRHamHnR" : {
        "2" : 8,
        "5" : 8,
        "6" : 12
      },
      "-Kgmc8U6LIBBXYBvBfu_" : {
        "5" : 8,
        "6" : 12,
        "7" : 10
      },
      "-KgmcIxN4CJTROqn3Ihu" : {
        "5" : 8,
        "6" : 12
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, `console.log(array);` logs the following arrays that increment in length:

```
 [ { days: '1', people: 6 } ]
[ { days: '1', people: 6 }, { days: '5', people: 8 } ]
[ { days: '1', people: 6 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 } ]
[ { days: '1', people: 6 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '2', people: 8 } ]
[ { days: '1', people: 6 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '2', people: 8 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 } ]
[ { days: '1', people: 6 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '2', people: 8 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 } ]
[ { days: '1', people: 6 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '2', people: 8 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 } ]
[ { days: '1', people: 6 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '2', people: 8 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 } ]
[ { days: '1', people: 6 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '2', people: 8 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '7', people: 10 } ]
[ { days: '1', people: 6 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '2', people: 8 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '7', people: 10 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 } ]
[ { days: '1', people: 6 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '2', people: 8 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '7', people: 10 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 } ]
```

I only need to retrieve **one array**, the **last array** logged by `console.log(array);`:

```
[ { days: '1', people: 6 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '2', people: 8 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 },
  { days: '7', people: 10 },
  { days: '5', people: 8 },
  { days: '6', people: 12 } ]
```

Then I need to sum the total number of people for each "days" key with a common value. 
For example, I would want this new array:

```
 [{ days: '1', people: 6 },
  { days: '5', people: 32 },
  { days: '6', people: 48 },
  { days: '2', people: 8 },
  { days: '7', people: 10 }]
```

Im using web admin in Node.js to access my Firebase realtime database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the first part is to use `value` instead of `child_added`. `child_added` asynchronously iterates through the children so there's no way of knowing when we're at the end. `value` will retrieve all the data at once and from there we should use two `forEach` loops to retrieve our data.

```
weeklyNightsHeld.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  let array = []

  snapshot.forEach(childSnapshot => {

    childSnapshot.forEach(data => {
      var weeklyData = {}
      weeklyData.days = data.key
      weeklyData.people = data.val()
      array.push(weeklyData)
    })
  })
  console.log(array) // We should have correct data here
})
```

For the part about getting the sum total of the days in the array, we can use the nifty `reduce` function on `Array`.

```
const daysReduced = array.reduce((a, b) => {
  if (Object.keys(a).length === 0) {
    a[b.days] = b.people
    return a
  } else {
    if (a[b.days])
      a[b.days] += b.people
    else
      a[b.days] = b.people
    return a
  }
}, {})
```

I've written my code in ES6, but it shouldn't be hard to translate to CommonJS if need be.